How does a race condition occur?
I have a single item pool implementation:
public class OneItemPool<T>
{
    private T? _item;
    private object _lockForChangeValue = new();
    private object _lockForPostItem = new();
    private object _lockForGetItem = new();

    public void PostItem(T item)
    {
        lock (_lockForPostItem)
        {
            // waiting for _item to be taken
            while (WeHaveItem())
            {
            }
            
            lock (_lockForChangeValue)
            {
                _item = item;
            }
        }
    }

    public T GetItem()
    {
        lock (_lockForGetItem)
        {
            // waiting for _item to appear
            while (!WeHaveItem())
            {
            }
            
            lock (_lockForChangeValue)
            {
                var item = _item;
                _item = default(T);
                return item;
            }
        }
    }
    
    bool WeHaveItem()
    {
        return !object.ReferenceEquals(_item, default(T));
    }
}

As you can see I don't have a lock inside bool WeHaveItem(), I know object.ReferenceEquals is not an atomic operation.
I know this can happen:

Thread A calling WeHaveItem() and sees that _item is null
Meanwhile Thread B is changing value of _item
Thread A continues execution under assumption that _item is null while its not true anymore.

Suppose _item is not null and Thread A is calling PostItem, then check WeHaveItem and wait for it to become null
while Thread B calls GetItem and changes _value to null 
Thread A will get the old result _item != null 
but this shouldn't affect Thread A at all, because Thread A next operation will be to recheck WeHaveItem
I think there won't be any problems.
But real tests show that this is not the case.
I set up my test like this
var pool = new OneItemPool<string>();
while (true)
{
    var threads = new List<Thread>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        var k = i;
        var thr1 = new Thread(() =>
        {
            pool.PostItem(k.ToString());
            pool.GetItem();
        });
        threads.Add(thr1);
    }


    foreach (var thread in threads)
    {
        thread.Start();
    } 
    foreach (var thread in threads)
    {
        thread.Join();
    }
}

One PostItem for one GetItem, but the test ends up deadlocking inside the PostItem and the _item value is not null.
This shows that two GetItem executed successfully for one PostItem.
If I add lock inside WeHaveItem the deadlock goes away.
I've been thinking about this for two days and can't imagine how this is possible.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem

Are you certain that you are seeing a deadlock and not just an infinite delay?

it spins endlessly in "while (WeHaveItem())" inside PostItem

I can't see how you could get a deadlock in the code above, but it is certainly possible to get an infinite delay.
The reason is that locks provide two things: Mutual exclusion and memory visibility. Mutual exclusion means that only one thread can lock each object at a time (e.g. _lockForGetItem). Memory visibility means that when thread A writes a value while holding the lock on an object, the change will be visible to thread B when thread B acquires the lock.
The issue is that you have to lock the same object in both threads to get this synchronization guarantee. When thread A updates _item while holding _lockForPostItem and _lockForChangeValue, there is no guarantee that thread B will ever see the update, since WeHaveItem() doesn't lock either of these objects.
If this is the issue you are seeing, it also explains why it helps to lock _lockForPostItem or _lockForChangeValue inside WeHaveItem().
An alternative solution is to declare _item volatile, which ensures that changes to _item are visible across threads.

In order to be able to declare the _item volatile, the T must have the class generic constraint.

This is not a direct answer to your question. It is just a demonstration that you could implement the OneItemPool<T> component pretty easily and effortlessly by using higher level .NET tools, like the BlockingCollection<T> class:
​public class OneItemPool<T>
{
    private readonly BlockingCollection<T> _queue = new(1);

    public void PostItem(T item) => _queue.Add(item);

    public T GetItem() => _queue.Take();
}

Not only it is dead simple, but also it has better waiting behavior. It doesn't burn a CPU core while waiting for an item to be added or removed, by spin-waiting. Instead it blocks the current thread, without consuming any CPU resources while waiting.
